# How can I make multiple client resources in xtext web editor using default Ace?

Tags: xtext

Stuck in where the server is saving the content of editor and how can I access or tweek it according to my use?
I want to have multiple clients hence multiple web editors and need to save the states and content of each client.

Comment: did you check https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-web/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.web.example.jetty/src/main/webapp/ace-statemachine-resource-multi.html

Comment: The statemachine example runs two resources on same web page (different browsers) whereas I need to have  multiple web pages as different clients and need to merge their results into one div in all of their individual web pages. How can I achieve that?

Comment: simply have different clients different resource ids should do the trick

Comment: I'm new to xtext web. Can you please indicate how and where I can do that?

Comment: i have no idea. in the multi page example you can see that both editors use different resource ids. i assume you can do the same.

Comment: Maybe I can make multiple html pages with different resource ids.

Comment: i assume you can set resourceId also in the options you call create editor in javascript with. so maybe a random id (woth correct file extension) works